# Python Selenium Having to Change URL Variable On All of My Test Cases

Tags: python, unit-testing, url, selenium

I have 10+ test cases at the moment and planning on creating several more. That being said is there a way that I can modify the URL variable once and that would change the variable in all my other scripts? I have this in all my of test scripts:

`class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://URL"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True`

I want to be able to be able to modify `self.base_url = http://URL`. But I don't want to have to do that 10+ times.

Comment: In Java, we use a .properties file and read URL from there. Or make all tests inherit from a Super class and define commonly shared data in your Super Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 good approaches to doing this,

1) Using a Configuration Manager, a singleton object that stores all your settings.

2) Using a basetest, a single base test that all your tests inherit from.

My preference is towards a Configuration Manager.  And within that configuration manager, you can put your logic for grabbing the base url form configuration files, system environments, command line params, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You should consider migrate your test to Page Object model.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/page-objects.html